# Button with rounded corners and border with color

Tags: android, button, rounded-corners

I need your help with something im trying to do, I've been trying to make a button with rounded corners and showing just the border of it, I need to be able to change the color programmatically depending on what I get from a web service, so far I tried to add the shape with a drawable and it gave the rounded shape with the border color, but I don't if is possible to change the color of it because its added by default in the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#ff000000"
    />

<padding android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"
    />

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```

that is the drawable I was using, then I tried to add the shape creating a custom class for the button and changing the onDraw method, and im getting a shape but is kinda weird

[image: Rounded shape]

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(strokeColor);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);

    int  h = this.getHeight();
    int  w = this.getWidth();
    //final RectF rect = new RectF();

    RectF oval1 = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(oval1, 40, 40, paint);

}
```

and for some reason besides the weird shape im adding the text programmatically with set text method and its not showing, it gets the color for the stroke but not the text

```
buttonCTA = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.btnCTA);
        buttonCTA.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(valueColor));
        buttonCTA.setStrokeColor(valueColor);
        buttonCTA.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one is what you need.

```
    public static void setRoundedDrawable(Context context, View view, int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    shape.setCornerRadius(20f);
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    if (borderColor != 0){
        shape.setStroke(2f, borderColor);
    }
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
}
```

You can change corner radius and stroke width depends on what you need. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me, with a few minor notes: The Context isn't necessary and the 2f in setStroke warned that it should be an int, not float.  My final take on it was:
 public static void setRoundedDrawable(View view, int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
  GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
  shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
  shape.setCornerRadius(10f);
  shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
  if (borderColor != 0){
   shape.setStroke(2, borderColor);
  }
  view.setBackground(shape);
 }

Answer (score 13):

create `round_background.xml` in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

set as background

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Change it at runtime with any view.

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
 GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)button.getBackground();
 drawable.setStroke(2, Color.YELLOW);
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually you could do this pretty easily with Material Design Button. IMHO using material design is the **standard way** of styling things in Android.

[image: rounded outlined button]

**Step 1:**

Add following dependency to module's `build.gradle` file and sync the project.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

**Step 2:**

Change your `style.xml` app theme to inherit from any of material components themes mentioned [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/).

ex:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
...
</style>
```

**Step 3:**

Change your button's xml to look like below

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnRound"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            app:cornerRadius="1000dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

- You could change the roundness of the button using `app:cornerRadius` attribute value.
- Set button's `style` attribute to `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` to make the button outlined.
- Use `app:strokeColor` attribute value to set the outline color.

---

**References:**

- https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/
- https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Answer (score 0):

Use `GradientDrawable` to get the view and modification:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)buttonCTA.getBackground();
drawable.setStroke(3, Color.your_color);
```

Here `3` is the predefined stroke width and `Color.your_color` is the color which will come from `WebService`.